# Exporter doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I'm using an old version of PF (3.5) but I can't get DataExporter to work with the attribute `selectionOnly="true"`.

If I don't set that attribute, everything works fine, vice versa I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/views/AreaRiservata/Clinipass/Malattia/malattiaScaricoMandatiTesoreria.xhtml @91,61 value="#{mandato.codCompagnia}": Cannot convert codCompagnia of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) ~[jsf-impl-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:186) ~[jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:174) ~[jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) ~[jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
```

My datatable looks like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update=":formTable:buttons" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update=":formTable:buttons" />
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update=":formTable:buttons" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":formTable:buttons" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":formTable:buttons" />

<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

<p:column filterMaxLength="4" filterBy="#{mandato.codCompagnia}" sortBy="#{mandato.codCompagnia}" width="75" id="amala">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Compagnia" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{mandato.codCompagnia}" />
</p:column>

<p:column filterBy="#{mandato.codProdotto}" sortBy="#{mandato.codProdotto}" width="75">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Prodotto" />
    </f:facet>                  
    <h:outputText value="#{mandato.codProdotto}" />
</p:column>

<p:column filterBy="#{mandato.annoSinistro}" sortBy="#{mandato.annoSinistro}" width="85">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Anno Sinistro" />
    </f:facet>                  
    <h:outputText value="#{mandato.annoSinistro}" />
</p:column>
```

```
<p:commandButton value="Crea file" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-document">
    <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tableScaricoMandatiTesoreria" fileName="Mandati" selectionOnly="true" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an actual fix but i've managed to bypass the issue by creating another datatable with

```
id="tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" style="display: none" value="#{malattiaScaricoMandatiTesoreriaModel.selectedMandati}"
```

Then I've changed the ajax's updates in the other table:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update=":formTable:buttons :formTable:tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update=":formTable:buttons :formTable:tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" />
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update=":formTable:buttons :formTable:tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":formTable:buttons :formTable:tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":formTable:buttons :formTable:tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" />
```

And the exporter now points to the new table:

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tableScaricoMandatiTesoreriaSelected" fileName="Mandati" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed **postProcessor** attribute in dataExporter Component

`<p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tableScaricoMandatiTesoreria" 
postProcessor="#{ExportCbean.postProcessXLS}" fileName="Mandati" selectionOnly="true" />`

Comment: postProcessor doesn't seem to be mandatory on the dataExporter. I'll give it a try even I don't know what to code in that method.